# Why does my custom scrollbar not show in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-plugins, scrollbar

The following jQuery code gives fine results in dreamweaver live view, but doesn't work in browser or fiddler:

```js
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.text-scroller1').each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      // field_category width bugfix
      /*if ($this.attr('name').indexOf('field_category') != -1) {
              var delta = 5;
            }
            else {
              var delta = 15;
            }*/
      var delta = 15;
      var width = $this.parent().width() - $this.parent().find('label').width() - delta;
      
    });

    $('.text-scroller1').mCustomScrollbar({
        axis: "y",
        theme: "dark"
      });
    });


})(jQuery);
```

```css
.text-scroller1 {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 5px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 30vh;
 overflow: auto;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/blob/master/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/blob/master/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<body>
<div class="text-scroller1 mCustomScrollbar">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. 
    </div>
  

</body>
```

I was trying to implement this: 
http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

How can I make it work?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like it works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/puwwfx3a/ Is this how it's supposed to function?

Answer (score 0):

The links of `jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js` and `jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.css` seem not correct.

Try to use

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js`

and

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css`